# How to vectorize the sum aggregation?

Tags: python, matlab, indexing, vectorization, graph-theory

I was trying to vectorize this piece of Python (or Matlab after some minor changes) code, which is the sum aggregation for a directed graph

```
for j in range(batchSize):
    for i in range(2*nEdges[j]):
        localSum[j,receivers[j,i],0:2]+=(localFeature[j,i,0:2])
```

I know how to drop one of the loops when it is `=`, but I failed to find a way to do it with this `+=` case. The difficulty to do the same trick lies in that `receivers[j,i]` could be the same value for different `j` and `i`s.

Do anyone have some idea on how to do the vectorization in this case?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it. `torch_scatter` package offers this functionality (for pytorch tensors). The nested loop can be rewritten as

```
localSum = torch_scatter.scatter(localFeature,receivers,dim=1,reduce='sum')
```